# html/css layout for Mastermind game

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm making a Mastermind game using html/js and I've almost got my goal layout, except for points A and B, see image below:

[image: my Mastermind board layout in html]

http://jsfiddle.net/5Saxg/

A: **What is the best way to layout the hintpegs as goal layout**, so they are shown on two rows instead of on one line? I mean, so they are shown like in the goal layout. I've tried using a 
 in the html, so like this

```
<div class="hintcontainer">
  <div class="hintpeg"></div>
  <div class="hintpeg"></div><br/>
  <div class="hintpeg"></div>
  <div class="hintpeg"></div>
</div>
```

But then it jumps down too much. Also when there are 3 or 5 hintpegs, what's the best way to make it "jump in" a little? So it's more like a honeycomb pattern instead of a grid. I've tried using SPAN element:

```
<div class="hintcontainer">
  <div class="hintpeg"></div>
  <div class="hintpeg"></div><br />
  <span style="margin-left: 10px;"><div class="hintpeg"></div></span>
  <div class="hintpeg"></div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work and besides I would have to add a lot of span elements, I'd rather use css as this would be easier to manage during the game.

B: What is the best way I want to add a indicator for when the player selects a color, which cycles through all the colors. It's like a small rectangle above the pegs at the bottom. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: For "A": Instead of floating all those elements i would count them with Jquery and based on the outcome place them. If the outcome is 3, put two on top and one centered below. If the outcome is 5, put 3 on top and the other two centered below.

Comment: But my question is; what CSS can I use to put it at the bottom and slightly to the right?

Comment: Put it in there own div container and put that container on margin:auto; But my guess is that it changes with game status, so you need to ask a different question. I can be wrong though...

Comment: Is this still something that needs solving, or should the question be closed/deleted?  It’s unlikely the original poster is still looking for an answer 3 years on. It’s also not a question that’ll help random users searching, especially since CSS has since gained capabilities (grid) that would make the solution for this case obsolete.